# Why WAF blocks multiple spaces?

Tags: api, web-application-firewall

In my project we are using WAF. Recently I found a bug that is, when we are adding multiple spaced words in a textbox for example

> Hello there,       this is a multi spaced word collection
> .

and trying to saving it, the WAF blocks the request, but when we try to save the text without space (more than one continues spaces) like this :

> Hello there, this is a multi spaced word collection .

it got saved.
I compared the formData from the network only the difference I could identify is the space. Why the WAF blocks the request? is that a built-in functionality to prevent cyber attacks?

Note: If I remove the extra spaces from my UI it works fine. So am very curious to know why the WAF blocks the request?